# Basic Shiny Reactivity: Download User-designated JSON file in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I have an AWS bucket with a bunch of dynamically generated JSON files. When a file is generated it gets a "slug".

I'd like to be able to copy that slug (from an outside website) and enter it in a Shiny textInput box, then add the rest of the URL to the slug, and download the designated file as an R object. (I use jsonlite::fromJSON here).

The code below works, and it generates the correct string and puts it into a box in the ui side. But I can't figure out how to use that output variable on the server side. It is hard-coding the "slug". I want to use the slug from the ui textInput.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)
library(jsonlite)
library(circlize)
library(chorddiag)
library(plotly)

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyjs)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = ""),
  dashboardSidebar(
    
    textInput("slug","Discovery ID",placeholder = "N79og8K"),
    fluidRow(box(textOutput("URL")))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

#  raw_data_URL <- "https://XXX.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"
#  raw_data_suffix <- ".json"
#
#  full_URL <- eventReactive(input$submit, {
#    paste0(raw_data_URL,"/",input$slug,raw_data_suffix)
#  })

#  output$URL <- renderPrint(full_URL())

  data <- fromJSON(paste0(raw_data_URL,"/","N79og8K",raw_data_suffix))
    
  )
}
```

I've tried all sorts of things with reactive objects, and haven't gotten anything to work.

Also, the commented out text does work too: it populates the box with the right string on "submit". But I can't get the server to go to the resulting file URL.

Can I use the output variable in my server app?

Comment: It doesn't look like you have any problem with Shiny reactivity.  Your problem is that you haven't written any code that fetches the resource from AWS.  `fromJSON` merely parses the JSON, it doesn't go and get it for you.  You probably need `httr` or something.  In any case, you should figure out how to get and parse the json outside of Shiny.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but that's not right. fromJSON does pull the file if you give it the direct url of the file. The code I posted does work. My problem is getting it to submit the url after it's been constructed (using the actionButton). I can get the correct string, but can can only use it on the ui side of the app. That's all the commented stuff. If I un-comment and try to use `output$URL()` on the server side, the code breaks.

Comment: It is difficult to help because your code does not even run.  For example, `dashboardPage` needs a body, you are missing the submit `actionButton`, you don't have the necessary `library()` calls or the `shinyApp` command that I had to look up.  Also, you do not give an accessible URL.  In any case, try to remove the `data<-` line, uncomment the code, and put the `fromJSON` function inside your `renderPrint`.

Answer (score 0):

The following app will prepare the URL, fetch it, and then modify it in the server.  It will print the output at each step.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(jsonlite)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("slug","Type in Name",value = "charlie"),
  actionButton("submit", "Submit"),
  textOutput("URL"),
  textOutput("raw_JSON"),
  textOutput("modified_JSON")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  raw_data_URL <- "https://api.genderize.io/?name="
  
  full_URL <- eventReactive(input$submit, {
    paste0(raw_data_URL,input$slug)
  })
  
  output$URL <- renderPrint(full_URL())
  
  full_JSON <- reactive({
    fromJSON(full_URL())
  })
  
  output$raw_JSON <- renderPrint(full_JSON())
  
  JSON <- reactive({
    full_JSON()$probability
  })
  
  output$modified_JSON <- renderPrint(JSON())
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I removed the `shinydashboard` package to make the solution more minimal.  Not every Shiny developer has or knows it.

The key point is that when you want to use something reactive, you have to treat it like a function and put `()` after it, like I did for `full_URL()`, `full_JSON()` and `JSON()` above.  Also, you can only use reactive objects inside of other reactives like `reactive()` and `renderPrint()`.

Comment: Thank you again, Michael. I've added the libraries in to my original post. Otherwise, yes, it is a pared-down, minimal example, and I did obscure part of the URL (for obvious reasons).

It's not a question about shinydashboard, in fact, I never even tagged it with that. It's about shiny reactivity.

The code you posted does work, yes, as I pointed out in my OP. It gives me a variable, `output$URL`, that I **can** use -- but only in the UI. I need to be able to use it in the server, but only when the user clicks "submit".

Comment: Does my answer work?

Comment: It works in the UI, but I can't use `output$URL` in the server. ```"Warning: Error in $: Can't read output 'URL'
  56: <Anonymous>
  50: dplyr::select
  49: mutate
  47: server [/Users/steveschultz/Desktop/repos/raditube/shiny_app/app.R#58]
   1: runApp
Error in output$URL : Can't read output 'URL'"```

Comment: the next line of code (not in the minimal example) is meant to be: ```  nodes <- output$URL$nodes %>% 
    dplyr::select(-thumb) %>% 
    mutate(type = if_else(title == "user","user","channel"),    # Making the graph bipartite
           count = replace_na(count,0),    # sets view counts for users to zero instead of NA
           title = if_else(type == "user",id,title)   #sets unique user titles```

Comment: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks again Michael. That didn't do what I need it to, but your name genderizer app is quite cute! I'm going to go back to the books on this and see if I can figure it out that way.

Comment: Okay, good luck.  My last suggestion is to try and separate the Shiny bits from the core (offline, traditional interactive R) logic.  Get working code that does what you want (ideally wrapped in a function) and then build a Shiny app around it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal reprex of what actually ended up working

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(jsonlite)
library(igraph)
library(plotly)
library(chorddiag)


  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(),
    dashboardSidebar(fluidRow(textInput("slug", "Discovery ID",value = "VJPEqQB")),
                     actionButton("submit", "Submit")),
    dashboardBody()
),

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  raw_data_URL <- "https://XXX-bucket.s3.us-west-1.amazonaws.com"
  raw_data_suffix <- "_graph.json"
  
  saveData <- function(data) {
    set.seed(1)
    data <- fromJSON(data)
    
  }
  
  # Construct the URL
  getURL <- reactive({
    data <- paste0(raw_data_URL,"/",input$slug,raw_data_suffix)
    data
  })
  
  # When the Submit button is clicked:
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    saveData(getURL())
  })
  
  # Show Outputs (omitted from MRE)
  
  # Not Used:
  output$graph <- renderPlot({
    input$submit
    plot(net) # net is a graph object derived from `data`
  })
  
}
)
```